# jQuery Datatables: Individual column searching not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have included the code that is present in this link: https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html

But it isn't working properly. The search boxes show up but on typing the details in the search boxes the data does not load. I will post the code that I have included in my file. Kindly have a look at it and verify the same.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank You.

**CODE**

```
        <div class="col-md-12" style="max-height:300px; display:block; overflow:auto;" >
    <table id="big_table" class="table table-striped display table-bordered">
        <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
    <th>Column 3</th>
    <th>Column 4</th>
    <th>Column 5</th>
    <th>Column 6</th>
    <th>Column 7</th>
    <th>Column 8</th>
    <th>Column 9</th>
    <th>Column 10</th>
    </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
    <tr>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
    <th>Column 3</th>
    <th>Column 4</th>
    <th>Column 5</th>
    <th>Column 6</th>
    <th>Column 7</th>
    <th>Column 8</th>
    <th>Column 9</th>
    <th>Column 10</th>
    </tr>
        </tfoot>        
<tbody>
    <?php foreach($array as  $arr) { ?>

    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $arr->column_1; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $arr->column_2; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $arr->column_3; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $arr->column_4; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $arr->column_5; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $arr->column_6; ?></td>
    <td style="text-align:right;"><?php echo $arr->column_7; ?></td>
    <td style="text-align:right;"><?php echo $arr->column_8; ?></td>        
    <td><?php echo $arr->column_9; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $arr->column_10; ?></td>
    </tr>       
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
// including input
$('#big_table tfoot th').each( function () {
    var title = $(this).text();
    $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
} );
// datatable initialization plus exporting to excel     
var table = $('#big_table').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'excelHtml5'
    ],
    "bFilter": false,
    "bInfo": false,
} );
//search
table.columns().every( function () {
    var that = this;

    $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
        if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
            that
                .search( this.value )
                .draw();
        }
    } );
} );       

} );
</script>
```

Comment: What do you get in the console? Also do you have a tbody? In the html code you posted it is missing and the code is incomplete.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: table is not defined

Comment: Alright so do you want the code for tbody as well?

Comment: which version of datatable and jquery are you using?

Comment: Version Number: 1.10.11

Comment: It works fine for me. Check this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UvjnT/579/). Make sure you are using the latest version of dataTable. This api is not supported in versions < `1.10`.

Comment: It has nothing to do with getting data from the database does it? Because the code you have written the data is hardcoded

Comment: Once the datatable is populated with data. It has nothing to do with the database unless it is ajax datatable(which in your case is not). Also please post the generated html instead of the php part. Try to imitate and make a code snippet or jsfiddle to see if works correctly.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I will have a look

Comment: It still isn't working on JSFIDDLE either  [https://jsfiddle.net/9htdrfum/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/9htdrfum/1/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Seems like `bFilter` attribute in your datatable init part is making the conflict for datatable to be non-searchable. According to the datatables site this attribute should be set to true if you want to search multiple columns individually. Try the below code for datatable initialization,

```
var table = $('#big_table').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'excelHtml5'
    ],
    "bInfo": false,
} );
```

This should work for you now. Check this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/9htdrfum/2/)

If you want to make the datatable global search filter to be disabled(hidden) then the dom should be set to `lrtp`. Eg: `dom: 'lrtp'`

Comment: @davidnoronha if you still want to disable the global search you can use the `dom:lrtp` attribute. Glad its working. ;)

Comment: We tried the exact same thing in our project and this still does not work; could you give some pointers please? The complete code for this has been posted by my teammate in this thread -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54127446/individual-column-searching-text-inputs-not-working-in-my-rails-code