# Individual column searching (text inputs) not working in my rails code

Tags: javascript, jquery

Individual column searching (text inputs) is not working in my rails code.
My mappings.js file :

```
            $(document).ready(function(){

              $("table[role='example_datatable']").each(function(){
                var dataTableInstance = $('#mappings').DataTable({
                    "order": [[ 4, "desc" ]],       
                  columnDefs: [  
                    { "searchable": false, "targets": 6}, 
                    { "orderable": false, "targets": 6}
                  ],
                  "bFilter": false,
                  dom: 'Bfrtip',
                  pageLength: 10,
                  processing: true,
                  serverSide: true,
                  ajax: $(this).data('url')
               });


              $('#mappings tfoot th').each(function(){
                        var title = $('#mappings thead th').eq($(this).index()).text();
                        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" name="'+title+'" />' );
                    });


              dataTableInstance.columns().every(function () {
              alert("hi");
              var datatableColumn = this;

              $(this.footer()).find('input').on('keyup', function () {
               alert("hi2");
               datatableColumn.search(this.value).draw();
              });
              });



              });
            })
```

My mappings.html.erb file:

```
            <%= content_tag :table, 
                            role: :example_datatable, 
                            id: 'mappings', 
                            class: 'table reconciletable table-striped table-bordered table-hover', 
                            data: { url: mappings_path(format: :json)} do %>

              <tfoot>
                <tr>
                  <th>Id</th>
                  <th>Entity</th>
                  <th>Item</th>
                  <th>Group</th>
                  <th>Record Created On</th>
                  <th>Record Created By</th>
                </tr>
              </tfoot>


              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Id</th>
                  <th>Entity</th>
                  <th>Item</th>
                  <th>Group</th>
                  <th>Record Created On</th>
                  <th>Record Created By</th>
                  <th></th>
                </tr>
              </thead>

              <tbody>

              </tbody>


            <% end %>
```

I'm able to get the input texts for each column but once I try searching & nothing happens and it's not able to filter my datatable according to column search. 
This is my code. please help me out :'(

Comment: What do you get in the browser console ? And are you sure that your api return the correct thing ?

Comment: browser console is empty no error

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//Apply the search
    table.columns().eq( 0 ).each( function ( colIdx ) {
        $( 'input', table.column( colIdx ).footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
            table
                .column( colIdx )
                .search( this.value )
                .draw();
        } );
    } );
```

[working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/a5jbqte6/)

Comment: i added a demo please check

Comment: yes i checked but that same code is not working . i will add my html page code as well