# Converting boolean datafield from lowercase 'true' to uppercase 'TRUE' in data table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables

Im trying to display my "Approved" data field, which is of boolean datatype, as `TRUE` and not `true`.

I've tried `approved.upcase!`, `approved.toUppercase()`, but both seem to provide ajax datatable error.

```
def data
  examples.each do |example|
    record = [example.approved, example.updated_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y at %I:%M%p")]
    result << record
  end    
  result
end
```

I expected the result `TRUE`, but I got `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to force this to be a string:

```
example.approved.to_s.upcase
```

You can't call things like `upcase` on `true` because it doesn't know what that method is. You need to convert to a string first, then you can do anything that a String can do.

When applied:

```
def data
  examples.map do |example|
    [
      example.approved.to_s.upcase,
      example.updated_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y at %I:%M%p")
    ]
  end
end
```

Since you're effectively mapping one entry, use [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-map) instead of a temporary array. This helps simplify your code considerably.

That being said, it's not clear why you'd want `"TRUE"` instead of `true` as if you're using AJAX, and likely JSON, you'd want native boolean values in there so that they show up as JavaScript `true` and not some arbitrary string.

Comment: can u help me with this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54127446/individual-column-searching-text-inputs-not-working-in-my-rails-code